# Group by week in Rails 4/Mysql db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Is there any way to group by week in rails AR

```
answers = Answer.all

daily_answer_count = {}
answer.where("val = 5").group('date(created_at)').count.map{|k,v| daily_answer_count["#{k.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}"] = v}

Output
{ 
"2016-03-05":  65
"2016-03-06":  57
"2016-03-07":  45
}
```

So the problem know is i need to create a hash map like above for weekly biases
so the key would be beginning of the week and value will be the total value of the week.

Any direct way of doing this using rails AR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, you can leverage grouping by some date/time functions, for example the [`YEARWEEK` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) which returns the year combined with week as an integer.

```
answer.where("val = 5").group('yearweek(created_at)').count
=> {
  201601 => 34,
  201602 => 35
}
```

If you wanted to group by week regardless of the year, use the [`WEEK` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week):

```
answer.where("val = 5").group('week(created_at)').count
=> {
  01 => 23,
  02 => 54
}
```

Take a look into the [`WEEK` function docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) to decide which precise definition of a week you desire (e.g. week starting from Monday vs. Sunday etc).

I'm sure there are similar functions in other databases as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Answer model add this:

```
def week
  self.created_at.strftime("%W")
end
```

Update the following code by this:

```
answer.where("val = 5").group_by(&:week).count.map{|k,v| daily_answer_count["#{k.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}"] = v}
```

Comment: `self` means. It is answer class model.

Answer (score 1):

```
answers.where(:val => 5).group('week(created_at)').count
  => {
        01 => 23,
        02 => 54
     }
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!